# How to set an option using a string in a vim script

Tags: vim

I am trying to set an option but it does not work when using a variable.

This is what actually works:

```
set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle/foo/foo.vim/
```

When I try this, it DOES NOT work anymore:

```
g:foo_path = '~/.vim/bundle/foo/foo.vim/'
set runtimepath+=g:foo_path
```

I have seen a similar topic here and they use the following command to set an option with a variable:

```
let &backupdir=s:vimetc.'backups/'
```

However, when I try this:

```
 let &runtimepath+=g:foo_path
```

It still DOES NOT work. I am getting:

```
 E734: Wrong variable type for +=
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: See also the "duplicate" on vi.SE: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11601/set-option-with-variables

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `set` does not support using string variables and `let` does not support += for string types.

This should work:

```
let g:foo_path = '~/.vim/bundle/foo/foo.vim/'
let &rtp.= ',' . g:foo_path
```

Comment: You could shorten it a little by using `let &rtp .= ',' . g:foo_path`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

another workaround

```
exe 'set runtimpath='.a:lines
```

after reviewer's comment, a 2.0 version

```
exe 'set runtimepath='.&runtimepath.','.g:foo_path
```

Comment: Prefer `exe 'set rtp+=rtp'.fnameescape(g:foo_path)`. Otherwise, you may end up adding in `'rtp'` a path that is already there.

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it. Appending *options* is done (regardless of the type of the option value, i.e. string vs. number) via `:set option+=val`, whereas the concatenation operation with String *variables* is done via `:let &option .= var`. You get the E734 error because `+=` with `:let` is for numerical addition only.